# rubber gem and time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

The default time zone in the rubber.yml file is

```
timezone: US/Eastern
```

What other time zone formats are supported?
Is it possible to use UTC?
For Europe is this correct?

```
timezone: Europe/Paris
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using UTC just fine:

```
timezone: UTC
```

Europe/Paris should work, as should any timezone on [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).